# In VSTS, how can I reference a variable in the name of another variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a variable group that contains deployment credentials for an environment, `test_host`, `test_token` etc. I want to be able to use the values of these variables in a release task but I don't want to type in the environment name (test) as this can change between environments.

How can I reference the `test_host` variable using the current environment name? I've tried `$($(Release.EnvironmentName)_host)` which results in the string `$(test_host)` being passed to my script. How do I get it to resolve `$(test_host)`?

Note - I am trying to pass these values into a powerhsell script so in the arguments field I have `-deployHost $($(Release.EnvironmentName)_host)` which results in `-deployHost $(test_host)` being executed.

**UPDATE 1**
Whilst the values ultimately get passed into a powershell script, that script is within a task group. If I do it outside the task group (just a regular powershell task in the release) then it works. When I pass the value into a task group parameter, it fails. See logs below.

```
2017-08-24T12:58:50.5643742Z Generating script.
2017-08-24T12:58:50.7206133Z Formatted command: . 'C:\agent_work\r5\a\RCV\deploys\uxforms\Deploy-ToUxForms.ps1' -targetHost $(test_host)
2017-08-24T12:58:50.7206133Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\agent_work\_temp\baf9f7b8-2de2-4760-8cfd-67cd530801ed.ps1"
2017-08-24T12:58:50.7206133Z ##[error]test_host : The term 'test_host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.

At C:\agent_work\_temp\baf9f7b8-2de2-4760-8cfd-67cd530801ed.ps1:2 char:79
+ . 'C:\agent_work\r5\a\RCV\deploys\uxforms\Deploy-ToUxForms.ps1' -targetHost $(te ...
+                                                                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test_host:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thanks

Comment: It is working fine for me. What's the detail log of PowerShell task? You can try to create a new release definition and try again.

Comment: BTW, I tested with PowerShell task with inline script type.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I created a new release and it worked, but it fails when passing in to a task group - please see update 1 above.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this issue with task group. Could you reproduce this issue with a new task group and new release definition? What're steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: This seems to be working now after recreating all my task groups and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated all task groups and variables and this works now.